# Unbound value in hand-created OCaml AST

Tags: compiler-construction, ocaml, abstract-syntax-tree

I am writing a compiler that takes in my AST and outputs an OCaml AST. When compiling:

```
(List.length '(1 2 3))
```

to

```
List.length [1; 2; 3]
```

I get the following output ast:

```
[
  structure_item (_none_[1,0+-1]..[1,0+-1]) ghost
    Pstr_eval
    expression (_none_[1,0+-1]..[1,0+-1]) ghost
      Pexp_apply
      expression (_none_[1,0+-1]..[1,0+-1]) ghost
        Pexp_ident "List.length" (_none_[1,0+-1]..[1,0+-1]) ghost
      [
        <label> ""
          expression (_none_[1,0+-1]..[1,0+-1]) ghost
            Pexp_construct "::" (_none_[1,0+-1]..[1,0+-1]) ghost
            Some
              expression (_none_[1,0+-1]..[1,0+-1]) ghost
                Pexp_tuple
                [
                  expression (_none_[1,0+-1]..[1,0+-1]) ghost
                    Pexp_constant Const_int 1
                  expression (_none_[1,0+-1]..[1,0+-1]) ghost
                    Pexp_construct "::" (_none_[1,0+-1]..[1,0+-1]) ghost
                    Some
                      expression (_none_[1,0+-1]..[1,0+-1]) ghost
                        Pexp_tuple
                        [
                          expression (_none_[1,0+-1]..[1,0+-1]) ghost
                            Pexp_constant Const_int 2
                          expression (_none_[1,0+-1]..[1,0+-1]) ghost
                            Pexp_construct "::" (_none_[1,0+-1]..[1,0+-1]) ghost
                            Some
                              expression (_none_[1,0+-1]..[1,0+-1]) ghost
                                Pexp_tuple
                                [
                                  expression (_none_[1,0+-1]..[1,0+-1]) ghost
                                    Pexp_constant Const_int 3
                                  expression (_none_[1,0+-1]..[1,0+-1]) ghost
                                    Pexp_construct "[]" (_none_[1,0+-1]..[1,0+-1]) ghost
                                    None
                                ]
                        ]
                ]
      ]
]
```

Upon inspection, this seems nearly identical to the output of `ocamlc -dparsetree` on the above OCaml program, which compiles successfully.

Instead, my program does not compile with the following error:

```
Error: Unbound value List.length
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wild guess: You are building a `Lident "List.length"`, which is wrong, `Lident` are only unqualified identifiers. You should use `Longident.parse "List.length"` which will give you `Ldot (Lident "List", "length")`

Side note: you should really output better locations. ;)

Comment: Regarding outputting locations -- I don't have support for that in my AST, unfortunately. Not yet.

Comment: I would advise to do that quickly. Debugging type errors is going to be a nightmare otherwise. :p

Comment: Agreed. I'm writing a series for building an interpreter/compiler in OCaml, and that has not yet covered a more complex reader/parser. I'll get there eventually.

Comment: In this case, you might be interested by using [malfunction](https://github.com/stedolan/malfunction), which is probably better suited if you intend to craft your language (including the type system) completely.